# Prevent card from stretching horizontally when using wider screens with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create cards that have an image on top and 3 small Text elements below. I want the layout to look something like this:

```
 ______________
|              |
|              |
|              |
|    Image     |
|              |
|              |
|______________|
text1      text2
text3
```

All of these items currently sit in an Inkwell, and I want text1 and text2 to be forced to opposite sides. I have them spaced correctly, but it's causing some weird behavior when changing the screen size. When expanding the screen it looks like this:

```
   ______________
  |              |
  |              |
  |              |
  |    Image     |
  |              |
  |              |
  |______________|
text1          text2
text3
```

Is there a way to stop the row from being larger than the image?

Here is the code:

```dart
InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    onTap: () => {},
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          child: Container(
            //fits the card, children fit the card - 10 from each side
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),

            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(
                        255, 161, 160, 159),
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .width *
                          0.1,
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .width *
                          0.22,
                      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .height *
                          0.22,
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.circular(3),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/img/test.jpg',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context)
                            .size
                            .width *
                        0.1,
                    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context)
                            .size
                            .width *
                        0.22,
                    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context)
                            .size
                            .height *
                        0.22,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .width *
                          0.1,
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .width *
                          0.18,
                      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context)
                              .size
                              .height *
                          0.18,
                    ),
                    child: const Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment:
                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment
                                  .spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Test 1",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Test 2",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize:
                              MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Test 3",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Here is a GIF of the current behavior:
[Current Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMefr.gif)

Comment: try to replace your code with my code, and let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: I've added a GIF with the current behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    onTap: () => {},
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Card(
          child: Container(
            //fits the card, children fit the card - 10 from each side
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 161, 160, 159),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.22,
                      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.22,
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/img.jpg',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.22,
                    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.22,
                  ),
                  child: const Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Test 1",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            "Test 2",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Test 1",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text(
                            "Test 2",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Handel your Inkwell position to handle the InkWell effect.

Comment: This results in basically the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with my code:

```
InkWell(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          onTap: () => {},
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  // Fits the card, children fit the card - 10 from each side
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.22,
                      maxHeight: 200.0, // Set a fixed maximum height for the image
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 161, 160, 159),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/image_one.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Test 1",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Test 2",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Test 3",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: This code caused the image to be flattened and didn't fix the width issue

Comment: okay, did it solve the problem of stretching the rows where you have texts too much?